# Different Views for iPhone 4 and 5

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone-5, iphone-4

I have some CGPoints that need to be different for iPhone 4/4S vs. iPhone 5/5S/5C.  How can I display different storyboards based on the iPhone screen size?  I have checked some of the other questions, but they aren't quite getting the job done.

Comment: Hi! As mentioned by @Enrico Susatyo, you can do this in the same storyboard using `autoLayout` or `autoSizing`. This [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) is a great point to start with. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have two separate Storyboard for the two sizes of the iPhones. There are two ways of achieving this:

- Use Auto Layout
- Use spring and struts

Without going into details on how to use those, you should be able to specify properties like "How far the view should be from bottom of the screen", etc. You can use those to differentiate the two screens.